# Linux image backup utility

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, backup, restore

Can anyone suggest a linux backup utility that can take a copy of the state with the current configuration so I can boot with it or install it on an external/new partition on a different machine?

Answer (score 1):

I used [Deja Dup](https://launchpad.net/deja-dup) which is installed in Ubuntu by default.
It's actually a front-end of Duplicity which you can use if you prefer command line approach.

Of course, there are several other solutions so take a look on a list 
[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem)